# do water heaters shut of when they fail?

Tags: plumbing

An example - Does an electric water heater shut its power off when (Feed) water source is shut off? I have a WAGS valve that will shut the water off when it fails, not sure about the power (Electric)

Comment: Your title and post body are asking two distinctly different questions.

Comment: Do you know if a high temperature limit switch or ECO (Energy Cut Off) in the tank is would shut off the unit if the water temperature exceeds 195 F. I believe I read about a AOSmith WH and that may be applicable for a gas powered WH, not sure... thank you for the prior Info.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off-topic. Please see the [Help center](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) for more information, and [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no. It'll heat and reheat the water indefinitely if the supply is shut off but the tank is left full.

If the power is left on and the tank is drained, the heating elements will probably self-destruct trying to heat non-existent water.

Of course, newer and more sophisticated models may have damage prevention mechanisms in place.